# Which tense is right to use?

Tags: tenses

In my test work, I had such a question:

> Children who (to come) to the cinema tomorrow
>   *[pick a form of the verb "to come" to make a correct phrase]*

Which tense is right to use, the Future Simple or the Present Progressive? I mean, should I use *will* after *who*? Will it be right if I use the Future tense, or is it better to use the Present progressive?

As I remember, our teacher explained to us that if we have **WHO** in the sentence, we can't use the Future tense; it's better to use progressive one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Emmy.  Perhaps you would like to visit our sister site ELL, for those who are learning English.  Your question may be considered off-topic here.

Comment: I am pretty sure the presence of "who" has nothing to do with the tense choice. Although "Who's coming ..." is much **much** better than "Who will come...", the latter is also technically correct but has a different meaning which I'm struggling to express. Therefore, I think this is an interesting question and I'd urge people to try to answer it rather than hastily close it.

Comment: @tchrist: Do you *honestly* believe this question is answered in the "duplicate" you linked?

Comment: @tchrist Why does that post deal with tenses in subordinate clauses?

Comment: Can we have the rest of the sentence please, Emmy? It will make a very big difference the answer! :)

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան The presence of "who" *might* have something to do with which tense we choose :) This is because we are more likely to just use the present tense if this is a subordinate clause. For example, if we compare "Children will come to the class tomorrow" and "Children who come to the class tomorrow, will have to use their own computers", the second only uses the present in the subordinate clause. So, in a way, the fact we might use the present simple in the first place is because of the *who*, it seems.

Comment: This question belongs on [ell.se]

Comment: Am I mistaken or the answer is very simple? If you need to emphasize the planned actions, then you use the Present Progressive. If a decision is spontaneous, then the Future Simple is  appropriate.

Comment: The answer depends on the definitions of phrase/clause being chosen. Focusing just on grammaticality,  'Children who come to the cinema tomorrow will see a marvellous film.' is fine. 'Children who are coming to the cinema tomorrow should bring a raincoat.' is fine.  'Children who will come to the cinema tomorrow include A, B and C. The rest have refused.' is fine. As usual, the test question (as set or as transmitted) is a poor one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a comma is mandatory after address, thus the two respective sentences would turn to be:

*Children, who **is going to** come to the cinema tomorrow?*

which is a question about **future happening/events**, but also about past decisions (who are the children who have already decided/planned to come). The latter is related to using "going to" for **planned activities**.

*Children, who **will** come to the cinema tomorrow?*

This is more about children's **will/intent** to come.

See, e.g.

> [The Song of Taliesin: Tales from King Arthur's Bard](https://books.google.ca/books?id=EuSGo-GvaWgC&pg=PA71&dq=%22who%20will%20come%20with%20me%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fHwqVbqkBLaasQTop4HoCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22who%20will%20come%20with%20me%20to%22&f=false) - Page 71 John
> Matthews - 2001
>
> "**Who will come with me to** fetch this thing?" Because I was among
> those who said they would go, I am able to tell this story.
>
> -
>
> [Boys' Book of Frontier Fighters](https://books.google.ca/books?id=4kpCAAAAIAAJ&q=%22who%20will%20go%20with%20me%20to%22&dq=%22who%20will%20go%20with%20me%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aH8qVeG8IYbbsATG-4HQCg&redir_esc=y)- Page 39 Edwin Legrand Sabin - 1919
>
> "**Who will go with me to** rescue Burr Harrison?" he thundered. The
> voices of the women were stilled; the men hesitated, looking one upon
> another. The Indians evidently were waiting for just such a try.

__

See this [forum discussion](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/2772989437) and [this one](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/2726058345?r=2726058345#2726058345).

You may want to see this famous grammar on the matter:

[**A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=olBgow5aJhAC&pg=PT262#v=onepage&q&f=false): Volume 4. Syntax (third ...
By **Otto Jespersen**

It excels on historical examples and considerations.

Also, perhaps the best contemporary presentation of English tenses:

[**The Grammar of the English Tense System: A Comprehensive Analysis**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=qFpkAIAOeg8C&pg=PA346#v=onepage&q&f=false), Volume 1
By Renaat Declerck, Susan Reed, Bert Cappelle

The links send you to relevant pages in each reference.

Comment: If they're asking about intent, native speakers are much more likely to say *"who wants to come"*.

Comment: I am talking about the examples at hand, trying to get the most out of them.

Comment: I'll agree that *who will* is often used for intent. But there is something strange about using *"who will"* to ask about intent for something that you assume everybody wants to do.

Comment: Well, I've just added two examples focusing on that.

Comment: *"Happy morning, Happy day! Who will come With me to play?"* is a children's rhyme in a story. I don't think it necessarily is a natural example of grammar. And I agree with the use of *"who will come"* in your King Arthur example.

Comment: No prob. Replaced.

Answer (score -1):

"Children, who will come to the cinema tomorrow?" tells us that the teacher is asking the children, who will go to the cinema the next day.

"Children who are coming to the cinema tomorrow,.." is simply addressing the children going to the cinema the next day.